# Command to display all descriptions of rakefile tasks?

Tags: ant, nant, rakefile, rake-task

I know in Ant / Nant you can pass an argument like -projecthelp to get a list of avaialbe targets with descriptions.

Is there a similar command-line argument for doing this with a rakefile's tasks?

Also is there a way to generate documentation from the rakefile itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake -T` lists tasks
`rake --help` shows other options

They are not necessarily 'targets' in Rakefiles though, they are just actions. Look at RDoc for documenting Ruby code

Answer (score 2):

```
rake -P
```

Displays tasks and dependencies.

```
rake -T
```

Displays tasks and descriptions

```
rake -T [PATTERN]
```

Displays tasks and descriptions *filtered* by that *PATTERN*. A pattern might be anything from `namespace:task_name` without the leading `rake` and without the prepended `# comment` (your `desc` from above a task/method).

```
# Example
namespace :example do
        # ^ searchable
    desc "Some task doing things"
    task :example do
       # ^ searchable
        puts "Hello world"
    end
end
```